# how to update nautilus past 3.26

Tags: apt, nautilus, 18.10

I am wondering how I would go about updating nautilus from 3.26 to 3.30, as I need it for an extension to work properly. I tried running apt-get upgrade nautilus with no success. Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 comes with 3.26 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=nautilus), so the upgrade of nautilus will come when you upgrade to 19.04 when released (my box has 3.30.4-stable on it). It's a core program, and would require a lot of updates to also occur (https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/nautilus to view dependencies), which likewise would cause a lot more updates - so your machine would become 19.04 pretty much to run it.  Your only alternative would be a snap type package, but being a core GNOME program I didn't find one.

Comment: would it be possible to update the entirety of gnome to a version that would be using nautilus 3.3?

Comment: 3.3 was used by Ubuntu 12.04; so do you really mean 3.3? or 3.30?  (it's not a decimal, it's three.thirty; major.release=3, minor.release=30). gnome 3.3 is EOL, 3.30 is currently in use by Ubuntu 19.04.  Ubuntu works on a release system, so the safest & easiest way to use gnome 3.30 is to just use Ubuntu 19.04; the development or 'testing' branch of Ubuntu. Ubuntu 19.04 is not supported on this site (it's off-topic), being supported elsewhere (eg. irc on #ubuntu+1)   Yes you can use 19.04 (I'm using it right now; why I have nautilus 3.30.4-stable) but be aware there is no help available here.

Comment: Yes I did mean 3.30 just accidentally kept putting .3, and where did you download your 19.04? I tried the daily builds and mine had nautilus 3.26 still

Comment: My box was a 17.10 daily build once upon a time, and I've just `do-release-upgrade -d` from that to what it is now (or about every six months), so I'd expect a daily-build to contain the same version as my installed Ubuntu 19.04.   I now only test Lubuntu & Xubuntu builds myself, so I've not looked at a GNOME flavored daily build, but I'd expect it to be the same as what I have installed (https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/nautilus) so check you have the 'disco' & current. I have a script grab mine, latest lubuntu comes from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/  (remove 'l')

Comment: ok, I see what was going on, when I installed gnome for myself on disco it came with 3.30, but ubuntu's version of gnome on disco is still 3.26. Thank you for your time and helpful ideas

Comment: I'm not a GNOME user, but as I recall the were specific things (like icons on desktop etc) that users wanted & expected from Ubuntu (ideas that were dropped for specific versions of gnome/nautilus/etc) causing Ubuntu to still use an older version that had them.  It's been well documented in Ubuntu Desktop newsletters/updates  (found these days on community.ubuntu.com)

Comment: makes sense, but luckily I do not need the icons, I just needed nautilus 3.30 for this application so all is good :)

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029010/how-do-i-install-nautilus-3-28-on-ubuntu-18-04